# Approximate position on circle for n points

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, approximation

I am struggling with the following problem:
I am given `n` points and a radius and I have to place them on a circle as symmetrical as possible.

Currently, I used something like this:

```
float theta = 360.0f / n;
int i = 0;
for (Word w : e.getValue()) {
    double newX = Math.sin(theta * i) * RADIUS + I_OFFSET_X;
    double newY = Math.cos(theta * i) * RADIUS + I_OFFSET_Y;
    mxCell v2 = (mxCell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, w.getValue(), newX, newY, OW_WIDTH, OW_HEIGHT,"shape=ellipse");
    graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", v1, v2);
    i++;
}
```

where `n` is my number of points.

This works fine for a large enough n, but for `n=3` for example, I get something like:

[image: n=3]

I would actually like to have something like:

[image]

(bad drawing skills are bad..)

So basically, something as symmetric as possible would be awesome.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks <3

Comment: What language is this? (And, possibly relevant, what graphic library?) Does it actually use degrees for `sin` and `cos`, as you seem to assume?

Comment: `Java` and `jgraphx` and yes, I assume they work with degrees but I could indeed be wrong

Comment: Well, that was easy. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html: "**cos** .. Parameters: a - an angle, in radians."

Comment: epic facepalm on my side. of course, it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jongware, the answer was quite obvious. Because I'm dealing with Java, all the `sin/cos` parameters should be in radians. 
Fix:

```
double newX = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta * i)) * RADIUS + I_OFFSET_X;
double newY = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta * i)) * RADIUS + I_OFFSET_Y;
```

Works like a charm